# FreeBSD: How to extend an encrypted ZFS zroot pool

Tags: freebsd, zfs, disk-encryption

I installed a vanilla FreeBSD 11.0 (amd64) and chose the installation option "ZFS on / (encrypted)" (or however it is really called). Now I have a nice ZFS pool:

```
root@storage:~ # zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
zroot  5.44T   943M  5.44T         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

root@storage:~ # df -ah
Filesystem            Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
zroot/ROOT/default    5.3T    299M    5.3T     0%    /
devfs                 1.0K    1.0K      0B   100%    /dev
zroot/tmp             5.3T     96K    5.3T     0%    /tmp
zroot/usr/home        5.3T    136K    5.3T     0%    /usr/home
zroot/usr/ports       5.3T    641M    5.3T     0%    /usr/ports
zroot/usr/src         5.3T     96K    5.3T     0%    /usr/src
zroot/var/audit       5.3T     96K    5.3T     0%    /var/audit
zroot/var/crash       5.3T     96K    5.3T     0%    /var/crash
zroot/var/log         5.3T    160K    5.3T     0%    /var/log
zroot/var/mail        5.3T     96K    5.3T     0%    /var/mail
zroot/var/tmp         5.3T     96K    5.3T     0%    /var/tmp
zroot                 5.3T     96K    5.3T     0%    /zroot
```

I currently have only one hardware RAID5 on my controller configured (aacd0). In the future I might add another RAID5 with the currently free slots of my server to extend the available storage (striped).

```
root@storage:/zroot # zpool status
pool: zroot
state: ONLINE
 scan: none requested
config:

NAME           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
zroot          ONLINE       0     0     0
  aacd0p3.eli  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

How would I add a second "disk" to my zpool than? Let's call that aacd1. I see that aacd0 is GELI encrypted, which is good - the key is prompted for on boot, I would like to be aacd1 encrypted with the same then.

I am missing the link here: how would I setup the second disk to be encrypted with the same key (only have to input and memorize one key for both disks) and add  that to the "zroot" pool?

Would it be wiser to install the OS on a non-zfs disk / stick and setup an encrypted ZFS striped pool from there? I can find a lot of documentation for this use case...

Comment: I'm not familiar with how FreeBSD does it, but very generally speaking, you would set up the new storage however you prefer, which obviously includes applying proper GELI, then simply `zpool add zroot /dev/aacd1p3.eli` (or whichever). **Keep in mind that after you do that, you will not be able to remove that chunk of storage from your pool!** If that last makes you feel at all uncomfortable, it's probably a good idea to practice in a snapshotted VM a few times first, where you can mess up however much you like and it won't matter beyond losing you a little of your time.